Is there a way to access IOS click on clock in status bar that takes you to top of screen in react?
I'm making a react app, not native, just react. I have a custom layout with custom scrollers.
Usually, on IOS devices if you click on the clock in the status bar (or around that area) it scrolls your page to the top. Since I have custom scrollers this feature doesn't work. Is there a way to access this gesture/ intercept it or something similar so I can run my own JS code when it happens?

It is recommended that you create a transparent view as a custom status bar, add a click event to it, and handle the event by scrolling to the top.

I am making a react web app i cant edit things out of the browser window i think.

If you can provide more information, it will be easier to offer better help.
You need to clarify how you are running this on iOS. Are you developing a web page using React and loading it in an iOS WebView container? Or are you developing a hybrid app using React Native?
If you are using the first approach, the WebView can be laid out starting from (0, 0), ensuring that the web page is positioned at the very top, including the status bar area. In that case, you can add a click event directly in the web page to handle it.
If it's the second approach, I'm not very familiar with it.

I'm not running it on IOS i am making a website with react and It will be used from safari on ios. Just a normal website not an ios app. But, the scroll to top when clickign the status bar function is an ios feature which i have no idea if i can access at all.

You can try listening to the scroll event, and window.scrollY === 0 indicates that the page has scrolled to the top.
